# How to set the { observe: 'response' } option globally in Angular 4.3+?

Tags: angular, response, interceptor

The first thought was to use an `HttpInterceptor` but the signature of the `clone(...)` method does not contain the `observe` option. Other than defining the `{ observe: 'response' }` option for each request, I don't see an alternative *yet* ...

So, is there, if any, method to set the `{ observe: 'response' }` option **globally**, e.g. via the `HttpInterceptor`?

```
clone(update: {
   headers?: HttpHeaders;
   reportProgress?: boolean;
   params?: HttpParams;
   responseType?: 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' | 'text';
   withCredentials?: boolean;
   body?: T | null;
   method?: string;
   url?: string;
   setHeaders?: {
       [name: string]: string | string[];
   };
   setParams?: {
       [param: string]: string;
   };
}): HttpRequest<T>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Interceptors are best used for setting headers on all requests, like the `Authorization` header. For global options though, you can make a wrapper method that you use instead of the HttpClient's `get()` method:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

get<T>(url: string, params?: { [param: string]: string }): Observable<HttpResponse<T>> {
    return this.http.get<T>(url, {
      params: new HttpParams({ fromObject: params }),
      observe: 'response',
    });
  }
```

This could be used inside your service or you could make a separate custom http service what wraps each method - post, patch, delete, etc.

Comment: maybe I will try tomorrow, but is it option to override the httpClient Mthods?

Comment: httpClient is the singleton class, and if you provide it in the root I think it will be overridden for the whole project

Comment: This is not an override, this is a wrapper. The wrapper method calls the httpClient method with your preferred options, so you don't have to specify them everytime

Comment: yes, I see, I want to try to override the httpClient methods, if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old but very interesting.

I thought about the overridden of the httpClient Methods.

You just need to override the methods once.
And all of the work will be done.

something like this for example for GET Method:

```
  overrideGetRequest() {
    const httpRequest = this.http.get.bind(this.http);

    this.http.get = function get<T = any>(url: string, options?: any): Observable<T> {
      let requestOptions = options || {};
      if(!('observe' in requestOptions)) {
      requestOptions = { ...requestOptions, observe: "response" };
      }
      return httpRequest(url, requestOptions);
    };
  }
```

And here is the Stackblitz example, where I have overridden the POST and GET methods of the httpClient.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interceptors-kknew1?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score -3):

You could add `{ observe: 'response' }` via `setParams` while cloning the reqeust like this:

```
request.clone(
    {
      setParams: { observe: 'response' },
      setHeaders: { 'some': 'header' },
      url: 'some.url'
    }
  );
```

...`setHeaders` and `url` is optional here.

Comment: The `{ observe: 'response' }` is an option, not a param

Comment: Yep, it's an option inside the first function paramter of the function `clone` as described in the angular docs https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#clone.

Comment: Yeah, but `setParams` is used to set the query parameters of the url, it has nothing to do with the http service's options such as observing the response.

Comment: That is, if you did this with url `http://www.example.com`, you'd get `http://www.example.com?observe=response`. That is not what OP is trying to do